# Reverse engineering the hex file

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering

reverse engineering the hex file 
Written in c language
From atmega16 
Want source code from the hex code
By reverse engineering need to extract the library file of the code 
 is their any possible way to do that
Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Those of us with voting power have marked your question as Too Broad.  Please give us more detail if possible

Comment: Want to extract source code from the hex code  to make changes in the extracted code and again recompile it

Comment: Does the package you want to reverse engineer exist in the AUR, or the ArchLinux base tree?  If not, you need to contact the vendor or have a look at their [Development Environment](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega16).

Answer (score 2):

There are no automatic tools which would do it for you. Reverse engineering requires in-depth knowledge of file format, instruction set, characteristics of the code generator used, and a lot of tedious work. You will most likely need to learn a lot of stuff before you can get started, or find and pay an expert who can do it for you if it is legal and worth it.

In general, situations in which you can legally reverse engineer code but have no access to its source are rare. Educational exercises (a.k.a. hacking for fun) are possibly a gray area.

Answer (score 1):

If you work for a company, please visit the [ATMega16 Product Page](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega16) and click the Development Environment Tab, that I alluded to in my comment.  Review the options there and choose the appropriate one.  After doing so, submit a Part Order to your company or decide to pay on your own.  As Hans-Martin Stated, there is more required to reverse engineer than there is to start from scratch.  If you came here hoping that you could find a cheaper or free way out, I'm sorry to be so blunt, but there probably is no way, even if the tools existed.